# What's required to configure VPN (over IPsec) server with FreeBSD which can accept connections from iPhone?

Tags: vpn, freebsd, ipsec

What's required to configure VPN (over IPsec) server with FreeBSD which can accept connections from iPhone? As I guess, the server should have ability to manage incoming connections, but I don't know to do that. And how to integrate the management system with VPN?

Answer (score 1):

The MPD project is the most up to date FreeBSD remote connection daemon. It provides a variety of connectivity including L2TP. See [the project's homepage](http://mpd.sourceforge.net/) for more information and [documentation](http://mpd.sourceforge.net/doc5/mpd.html).

Alternatively, you can go the old way of using a dedicated L2TP daemon. I found a link to a [lousy article on setting up FreeBSD for iPhone VPN connections](http://kuapp.com/2010/07/14/how-to-setup-l2tpipsec-vpn-on-freebsd.html). It seems to be current enough that it would work, most of these older L2TP daemon projects are abandoned at this point though.

Basically you need:

- The kernel recompiled with all the IPSec stuff
- Racoon (IKE Daemon) from the ipsec-tools port
- A L2TP Daemon like xl2tpd, openl2tp, or l2tpns

Other parts/layers are optional and will depend on your exact situation.

Comment: Is this still the best answer eleven years later?